# Istio 1.3+ apply http filter only for specific routes

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I have an EnvoyFilter ressource that is doing an http call to an authentication service. This filter is applied to the SIDECAR_INBOUND and it's working very well. I just have to deploy my POD with a certain label and the filter is applied. So, every incoming requests on that POD are authenticated by this filter.

But recently, some team mates wanted a new feature : the possibility to have public routes and private routes in the same POD. So I need to execute the filter only if a private route is called (for example /private/getUsers or /public/getUsers).

With the 1.3+ release of Istio I can see that the filter management has been completly refactored with new capabilities and features. But the Documentation is not very helpful and I don't know if the new version of EnvoyFilters is able to respond to my need.

Do you know if its possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you also provide your K8s version? As per Istio doc:
Istio 1.3 has been tested with these Kubernetes releases: 1.13, 1.14, 1.15.

Comment: Today we are using K8S 1.11.8 with istio 1.2.5, and we recently deployed istio 1.3.3. Everythong is working godd (as before)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is **impossible**. You can only match to fields mentioned [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/envoy-filter/#EnvoyFilter-RouteConfigurationMatch), but not individual routes.

Below you can find example which will apply to all routes but you cannot match specific paths.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: httproute
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        request_headers_to_remove: [foo]
```